# Delaying an action for a period of time

Tags: c#, multithreading, timeout, delay, execution

I am currently working on a screensaver launcher, but I want to delay the activation of the screensaver for a period of time to ensure the mouse position is still in the position to activate it, to prevent accidental activation. I am thinking some kind of thread to check the position of the mouse for x secs before execution, would this be a sensible solution?

> I'm not writing a screensaver, I have written an application so that
>   when you move your mouse to a designated corner of your desktop, the
>   screensaver comes on... I want to know how to add a delay to when you
>   move the mouse into that corner to prevent accidental launching of the
>   screensaver

If so how?

Comment: There is an API to manage the Screensaver. Are you talking about that?

Comment: Writing my own "Hot Corners" type application using Low Level mouse hooks. I have all that working, just looking for a way to delay the launching of the screensaver once the mouse is in the "activation zone"

Comment: No, a screen saver that pays attention to the mouse position makes no sense at all.  It is not supposed to *activate* when a human is moving it around.  Think this through a bit.

Comment: I think you are both misunderstanding me. I'm not writing a screensaver, I have written an application so that when you move your mouse to a designated corner of your desktop, the screensaver comes on... I want to know how to add a delay to when you move the mouse into that corner to prevent accidental launching of the screensaver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so that when you move your mouse to a designated corner of your desktop, the screensaver comes on...

When the mouse gets there, set a boolean and a timer. Make any mouse action clear the boolean.
Only when the timer fires and your flag is still there, proceed.

In other words, use a little state machine.

Comment: Went for this solution, works a treat, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code

```
   var CurrentMouse = ...; // Get mouse coordinates.
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(        
   (s) => {
            Thread.Sleep(500); // Half a second

        //  if (Mouse did not move)
        //     Launch Screen Saver

   });
```

EDIT:
Note this doesn't speak to invoking back to gui layer or thread locking. See the inspiration for this situation on my blog article entitled [C# MultiThreading Using ThreadPool, Anonymous Delegates and Locks](http://omegacoder.com/?p=262) which does show proper locking.

Comment: Another not really relevant answer that has a link to your blog.